# if condition without else option in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:-

```
pc_assign(username,pc_name)
pc_detail(os_id,ipaddress,pc_name)
pc_configuration(pc_name,hw_serial_no,model_no)
hw_property(value,hardware,hw_serial_no)
bl_os(os_id, os_name,version)
```

I need to create following view:-

```
pc_config(`username`,`pc_name`,`motherboard-  model_no`,`cpu(GHz)`,`RAM(GB)`,`HDD(GB)`,`Montior`,`ip_address`,`OS`)
```

For this I am writing following query:-

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW      `pc_config2` AS select `a`.`username` AS `username`,`a`.`pc_name` AS   `pc_name`,if((`p`.`hardware` = 'motherboard'),`c`.`model_no`,`NULL`) AS   `motherboard_model_no`,if((`p`.`hardware` = 'cpu'),`p`.`value`,`NULL`) AS `cpu(GHz)`,if((`p`.`hardware` = 'RAM'),`p`.`value`,`NULL`) AS `RAM(GB)`,if((`p`.`hardware` = 'HDD'),`p`.`value`,`NULL`) AS `HDD(GB)`,if((`p`.`hardware` = 'monitor'),`p`.`value`,`NULL`) AS `Montior`,`d`.`ip_address_192_168_1_` AS `ip_address_192_168_1`,`d`.`os_id` AS `OS` from (((`pc_assign` `a` join `pc_detail` `d` on((`a`.`pc_name` = `d`.`pc_name`))) join `pc_configuration` `c` on((`d`.`pc_name` = `c`.`pc_name`))) join `hw_property` `p` on((`c`.`hw_serial_no` = `p`.`hw_serial_no`)))

And the output is:-

```
username    pc_name motherboard_model_no    cpu(GHz)    RAM(GB) HDD(GB) Montior   ip_address_192_168_1  OS
nitu.dhaka      pc1     NULL                4.5         NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
soha            pc1     NULL                4.5         NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
nitu.dhaka      pc1     mboard              NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
soha            pc1     mboard              NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
nitu.dhaka      pc1     NULL                4.5         NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
soha            pc1     NULL                4.5         NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
nitu.dhaka      pc1     mboard              NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
soha            pc1     mboard              NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL        208                 1
```

Here what acutally happening is when query is runnig fore motherboard all its correspondant filed will be null. This is due to 
if((`p`.`hardware` = 'motherboard'),`c`.`model_no`,`NULL`) AS `motherboard_model_no`
The Null in second part. Is it possible the query without its second option (like null here)

I wan output something like following:- 
username    pc_name motherboard_model_no    cpu(GHz)    RAM(GB) HDD(GB) Montior ip_addres‌​s_192_168_1  OS
 nitu.dhaka  pc1     mboard  4.5     NULL   NULL    NULL     208     1 
soha     pc1 mboard  4.5     NULL   NULL    NULL     208     1
 And here i only inserted the values for motherboard and cpu only. if I will insert values for other field it will again get duplicate. How do i remove these lots of null

Answer (score -1):

What you look for does not really make sense: let's see:

With every query you create a dynamic table holding the result of the query. A table always is rectangular, it cannot take other shapes. A rectangular construction has rows and columns and these define cells. A cell has to exist, there cannot be a "hole" instead. Maybe the cell is empty or takes the value NULL (which is technically spoken the "better" emtpy value). But it does exist.

So when you design your query you have to define what value comes into each cell. If you use a conditional statement you can decide on-the-run which value to pick , but you have to pick one value, whichever that is. You cannot decide *not* to create or fill a cell.

So the question left is only: what value do you want to assign as "no value"? Technically a NULL is a good thing for processing cells. But it might be less suited if you want to present the table, that is unless you do not implement a human readable way to symbolize "NULL" (maybe "-/-"?). So maybe all you want to do is use the empty string in your else part of the conditional instead of NULL? This would deliver a table which does not show any value in "empty" cells when visualized directly. So just replace the NULL in your else part: `if((p.hardware = 'monitor'),p.value,'')` and all is fine.

Comment: I wan output something like following:-
username pc_name motherboard_model_no cpu(GHz) RAM(GB) HDD(GB) Montior ip_address_192_168_1 OS
nitu.dhaka     pc1     mboard             4.5         NULL NULL NULL     208                 1

soha         pc1     mboard             4.5         NULL NULL NULL     208                 1

And here i only inserted the values for motherboard and cpu only.
if I will insert values for other field it will again get duplicate .

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you are trying to say by this comment.